# phpunit no tests executed

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a 'No tests executed' with phpunit..

This line works

```
$ phpunit install/InstallDbTest.php
...
<result expected>
...

$ cat suites/installtests.xml   
<phpunit>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="database">
            <file>install/InstallDbTest.php</file>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>

$ phpunit -c suites/installtests.xml 
PHPUnit 4.7.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.



Time: 130 ms, Memory: 11.25Mb

No tests executed!
```

Does anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to correct the path in your phpunit.xml.

It is trying to find the file`suites/install/InstallDbTest.php`.  Since the file doesn't exist, no tests are run and you get the message.

Change the configuration to the following:

```
<phpunit>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="database">
            <file>../install/InstallDbTest.php</file>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

File paths in phpunit.xml are all relative to the location of the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in the *InstallDbTest.php* file you are missing:

```
<?php
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who you use a different *bootstrap* file than the Composer's autoload file, make sure you don't `use` one of your test case classes.

Indeed, PHPUnit (version 6.2 in my case) add to the running `TestSuite` all PHP files for which *no class is loaded yet* (see how it's done [in the code](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/6.2/src/Framework/TestSuite.php#L321)). From the `TestSuite::addTestFile($filename)` method:

```
$classes = get_declared_classes();
$filename   = Fileloader::checkAndLoad($filename);
$newClasses = \array_diff(\get_declared_classes(), $classes);
```

So if your class already belong to the `get_declared_classes` it will be ignored.

To summarize: don't `use` your test class before ;)